# Is there a way for adding multiple n elements to end of vector in O(1) complexity for C++17

Tags: c++, data-structures, stdvector, push-back

I have try to develop an algorithm and in some times i should add multiple elements of a vector to another vector's end. Is there a way to proceed this in a constant time?

Also, is there a way for another data structures(such as arrays and iterators) to do that. I am not be restricted to use the vector.

> //O(n) complexity

> ```
> void add_to_vec( const std::vector<int>& src, std::vector<int & dest, int start, int n )
> {
> for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
> dest.push_back( src[start + i] );
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: No, you cannot add (in c++ terminology, `push_back()`) O(n) elements in O(1) time on a non-parallel machine.

Comment: There is no way to do an operation involving a variable number of elements in constant time.

Comment: But you can add multiple elements to a vector in a single line of code, but it remains an O(n) operation.

Comment: You can use std::vector's insert. But if you add n elements that would still be an O(n) operation.

Comment: I think you are perhaps confused about what O(n) and O(1) (or constant time) mean. If so then please rephrase your question without these terms.

Comment: What if you always add 5 elements?

Comment: @user4581301 Then that would be constant time. It's the variable part that makes it not constant time.

Comment: Okay there is variable part n but, think as linked list if we change the next pointer of the last element of a linked list to another linked list begin node, we append the variable number elements in constant time.  Is there a similair mechanism in vectors or another type other than linked list?

Comment: So then maybe you simply want a `std::list` instead.  [`std::list::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) is O(1).  (Though of course, it required O(n) time to create the other list in the first place.)  Now, if you need O(1) splicing *and* O(1) random access, things get harder.

Comment: @NateEldredge Note that ```list::splice``` is still O(n) when you use it to splice N elements (also via the iterator range version). While the splicing itself is O(1), the method has to loop through the elements to count them and update the list's size

Comment: @Homer512:  True.  But it's O(1) when you splice in an entire list (whose size would already be known), which would serve OP's purpose if the N elements to be appended were their own list.

Comment: @john Depends on operation and what *involving* means. E.g. for vector-like container with trivially destructible element type erase *n* elements from the end (shrink) without re/de-allocating can be O(1) if optimizer avoids destructor calls (which are no-op). Similarly for resizing to bigger size (increase by *n*) if there's trivial default constructor. So, these operations involve (destroy/construct) *n* objects but can have O(1) complexity.

Comment: Why would you think that's possible? A vector needs to allocate storage for the new elements. Then it needs to construct/copy/move elements. How could that possibly be done in O(1) time for an arbitrary number of incoming elements?